# Is the object being returned temporary or anonymous, and could it cause memory leaks?

Tags: c++, dynamic-memory-allocation

First off, when returning an unnamed object such as:

```
Object* func() { return new Object(); }
```

is that an anonymous variable, temporary variable, neither, or both? Does having it unnamed cause it to be temporary- as in it goes out of scope once func returns? Could I extend its scope by assigning it to a pointer or reference in the calling code block or would that be illegal/dangerous?

My second worry is that since it is created with `new` if I were to:

```
Object *var = func()
```

somewhere else, would I need to `delete` it afterwards? If I did not delete it I'm assuming that would cause a memory leak.

If instead I returned a reference:

```
Object& func() { return new Object(); }
```

and I assigned the new object to a pointer or reference, would accessing the object be illegal/dangerous?

Also, if I am missing any other terminology here, please say something about it.

Comment: The solution to all your problems: smart pointers (unique_ptr/shared_ptr, boost may have other variations as well)

Comment: This `Object& func() { return new Object(); }` does not compile

Comment: And you might just want to `return Object();`. In particular if your class supports [moving](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor).

Comment: I suspect that you don't realize that when you say "is *that* an anonymous...," you are referring to two completely different things by "that". One is the pointer value that you are returning. The other is the object you allocated by calling `new`. They are two different things that can have different lifespans, be passed different ways, and so on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Object* func() { return new Object(); }
```

This allocates an object with `new` (that must be freed with `delete` or there will be a leak) and returns a pointer to it by value.

```
Object& func() { return new Object(); }
```

This is illegal. It claims it returns a reference to an `Object`, but `new Object` returns a pointer to an object. If we fix that:

```
Object* & func() { return new Object(); }
```

We still have a problem -- this allocates an object with `new` and returns a reference to a temporary pointer to it. This is illegal -- you can't return a reference to a temporary. It's no different from:

```
Object* & func() { Object* j = new Object(); return j; }
```

It should be clear that this is invalid. You're returning a reference to `j`, but `j` no longer exists after you return.

Though it's not idiomatic, you could do this:

```
Object& func() { return *(new Object()); }
```

This allocates a new `Object`, and returns a reference to it. The `Object` is not a temporary, so this is safe. The caller would still have to `delete` it to avoid leaks.

The object you allocated and the pointer to it that's returned by `new` are two different (but related) things.

The idiomatic way to do this is just to return the object by value. If you must dynamically allocate it, you should use some kind of smart pointer to avoid manually managing the lifetime.

Answer (score 1):

New will dynamically allocate a new variable of that type. You can use it for any type. You will **definitely** need to call delete in order to free that memory.

You can't return new as a reference. You're trying to cast from a pointer to an class, and that doesn't work.

Comment: I see, so it would be best to also add a `void freeFunc(Object *param) { delete param; }` and associate the two somewhere in documentation for example

Comment: Yes. As a good practice, you could even keep a counter, and increment it when you call new, then decrement when you call delete. If the number is greater or less than 0 in the end, you did something wrong.

Comment: @Nōmennōnhabeō The idiomatic, best practice way would be to return a `std::unique_ptr<Object>` so it would be **deleted automatically** (without additional overhead), and the users of that function would know what the **owning semantics** are *without even looking at the documentation*.  (Provided it has to be dynamically allocated, otherwise a plain `return Object();` would be best.)

Comment: @Puppy well I'm answering the question. Whether this is the best way to go or not is irrelevant.

Comment: @zenith Thanks, I guess the lesson here is to use higher-level abstractions when available

Comment: @Nōmennōnhabeō programers are forgetful :) it's best to hide implementation behind abstraction so you don't have to think about it.

Answer (score 0):

> Could it cause memory leaks?

Yes. When you use pointers with `new`, you need to explicitly free that memory with `delete`. 
If you're not very careful, chances are you will leak that memory.

The below code returns a pointer to the new allocated memory, i.e the beginning of that memory.

```
Object* func() { return new Object(); }
```

---

Smart pointers can make your life easier by managing their lifetime, and free the memory for you. Example:

```
shared_ptr<Object> var = make_shared<Object>();
```

(If you know the object won't be shared, you could use `unique_ptr`)

Or more relevant to you:

```
shared_ptr<Object> func()
{
    return make_shared<Object>();
}

int main()
{
    shared_ptr<Object> var = func();
}
```